# How do I implement login functionality in angular js application?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an application which uses angularjs 1.6 for the frontend and codeigniter for the backend. Till now the home page in my application had the login form and the logic for that functionality was written in homeCtrl.js. Due to new design changes for the application, the login form is now part of the header. So I am clueless about how to implement the login functionality throughout the application as the header will be a part of all the pages. Can I use the existing code without breaking the functionality as I have a deadline to meet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement this logic. Use proper routing. 
You can refer to this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router).

**Make use of UI-Router**

> This article makes use of ui-router library which you need to include.
>   In normal scenarios you will be having only simple states and one
>   state will be assoaciated with one view. But here you can configure
>   multiple views with your state.

**UI Router with Multiple Views**

> In your case, for the home page header will contain the login form.
>   And for the other pages it will contain the actual header or whatever
>   you want. You can configure as many sub screens as you want.

You may get the UI-Router cdn path [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-router)